# User defined c# Control for embedding into Microsoft Office & Powerpoint

Tags: c#, wpf-controls, ms-word, custom-controls, ms-office

I want to create an own charting control, which can be embedded and used in office documents. 
the control should be passive, if the user does not interact with it. when the user clicks on it, also new ribbon controls etc should be possible.

what is the best solution to establish something like that? 
some years ago, this was possible with ole objects. is that still a good solution, or are OLE control elements dead ended? what are the following technologies?

are there any good WPF or winforms solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chapter 13 of Carter & Lippert "Visual Studio Tools for Office 2007" is on using Windows Forms and WPF in VSTO.

Short answer, VSTO has Windows Forms control support, including a control called ElementHost which allows you to use WPF controls.

Googling 'vsto elementhost' yields [this](http://xamlcoder.com/cs/blogs/joe/archive/2007/07/17/using-wpf-with-vsto-office-2007.aspx), for example.

Comment: thanks, but this is just for addins?! is it also possible to embedd a form / control into a document?

Comment: Yes when you do that an ActiveX control called Windows Forms control host is added. There are some limitations/workarounds which Carter & Lippert document.